# Prove matrix convexity

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis

I need help to prove the following is false.

> Consider the function $f : \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3} \to \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ defined by $$f(X) := X^2$$ $f$ is convex with respect to the cone $\mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}_{+}$

---

I have proved that the above is true if $X \in \mathbb{S}^{3 \times 3}$, where $\mathbb{S}$ denotes the set of symmetric matrices. In this case, it is easy, since for a symmetric matrix we have $X^T = X$, and we also know that the norm of a matrix (e.g., $\Vert X \Vert^2_2$) is convex in $X$. But without the symmetry property, I am stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As written, $f$ is a matrix-valued function, so I don't understand what convexity means here. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @RobertBassett It means convex with respect to the order induced by the given cone.

Comment: Is the extra $>$ in the power of the reals a typo. or does it have some deep inner meaning?

Comment: Have you tried any simple examples??? The first example I tried failed.

Comment: Simply verify that $\frac12(f(X)+f(Y))-f\left(\frac{X+Y}{2}\right)$ is PSD when $X$ and $Y$ are PSD. This should be straightforward.